# Is this solutions to Ahlfors 1.1.4 #3 correct, or is there a typo?

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

Is the solution above correct? In particular, the second last line contain typos and it should be $0=(1-|a|^2)(1-|b|^2)$ correct? I've been stuck on that line for the past 20 minutes thinking I must have missed an obvious complex identity involving the modulus, but now I'm starting to think it's just a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You you are right that
$$
\begin{align}
 &|a-b|^2 = |1-\bar a b|^2 
\\
\iff& \cdots \\
\iff & 0 = 1-|a|^2 -|b|^2 + |a|^2|b|^2 \\
\iff & 0 = (1-|a|^2)(1-|b|^2) \, .
\end{align}
$$
This can be factored as
$$
0 = (1-|a|)(1+|a|)(1-|b|)(1+|b|)
$$
which *is* equivalent to
$$
0 = (1-|a|)(1-|b|)
$$
because the other two factors can not be zero.

So both conclusions are correct: It could be that the author of the solution meant $0 = (1-|a|^2)(1-|b|^2)$ but forgot the exponents, or they meant $0 = (1-|a|)(1-|b|)$ without mentioning the extra steps.